# Using JavaScript reduce to update and add to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I am trying to solve an issue in JavaScript, and believe using the `reduce` method would be most elegant. I have one array of objects that looks like this:

```
let existingLots = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'one',
        colour: 'red',
        speed: 100
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'two',
        colour: 'blue',
        speed: 70
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'three',
        colour: 'white',
        speed: 120
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: 'four',
        colour: 'yellow',
        speed: 90
    },
]
```

And another array that looks like this:

```
let newLots = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'one',
        colour: 'orange',
        speed: 100,
        owner: 'Ted'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'two',
        colour: 'blue',
        speed: 75
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'three updated',
        colour: 'white',
        speed: 120,
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: 'four',
        colour: 'yellow',
        speed: 90
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        title: 'five',
        colour: 'green',
        speed: 50
    },
]
```

As you can see, there is overlap between some ids. I would like update the `existingLots` array, so that if an object shares the same `id` as one in the `newLots` array, the object is updated with any new properties/values that are in its `newLots` counterpart. Also, I would like any objects that are in `newLots` (ie the one with the `id` of `5`) that aren't in `existingObjects` to be added into the `existingObjects` array.

I have tried with the following but have not achieved the desired outcome:

```
const res = existingLots.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    let updatedObj = newLots.filter(newLot => newLot.id === obj.id);
    // if object exists in currentLots, merge it
    if(updatedObj) {
        [...acc, {...obj, ...updatedObj}]
    } else {
        let newObj = !newLots.filter(newLot => newLot.id === obj.id);
        [...acc, {...newObj}]
    }
    return acc
}, [])
```

I am new to JavaScript array methods so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** You are using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which will return an array of filter elements

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
> the test implemented by the provided function. - MDN

**2)** This code just push/add all objects after the last element in the array and then discarded since you are not storing them anywhere

```
[...acc, {...obj, ...updatedObj}]
```

**SOLUTION:** You can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop over the `newLots` array and add data to `existingLots` element

```
newLots.forEach((newLot) => {
  let objExist = existingLots.find((o) => o.id === newLot.id);
  if (objExist) {
    for (let key in newLot) objExist[key] = newLot[key];
  } else existingLots.push(newLot);
});
```

or

```
newLots.forEach((newLot) => {
  let index = existingLots.findIndex((o) => o.id === newLot.id);
  if (index !== -1) existingLots[index] = { ...existingLots[index], ...newLot };
  else existingLots.push(newLot);
});
```

```js
let existingLots = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "one",
    colour: "red",
    speed: 100,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "two",
    colour: "blue",
    speed: 70,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "three",
    colour: "white",
    speed: 120,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "four",
    colour: "yellow",
    speed: 90,
  },
];

let newLots = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "one",
    colour: "orange",
    speed: 100,
    owner: "Ted",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "two",
    colour: "blue",
    speed: 75,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "three updated",
    colour: "white",
    speed: 120,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "four",
    colour: "yellow",
    speed: 90,
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "five",
    colour: "green",
    speed: 50,
  },
];

newLots.forEach((newLot) => {
  let index = existingLots.findIndex((o) => o.id === newLot.id);
  if (index !== -1) existingLots[index] = { ...existingLots[index], ...newLot };
  else existingLots.push(newLot);
});

console.log(existingLots);
```

Comment: Works perfectly and I learned a lot, thank you!

Comment: Can you achieve the same thing with `.reduce`?

Comment: Yes I can achieve with `reduce` also. @s3c

Answer (score 0):

I think the only place where you may use some "magic" is the lookup. This code creates a `map` between object id-s and their index in the actual array, and then loops over the updater-array, finding and updating existing object using the `map`, and simply appending the object if it's `id` is brand new.

```js
let existingLots = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'one',
    colour: 'red',
    speed: 100
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'two',
    colour: 'blue',
    speed: 70
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'three',
    colour: 'white',
    speed: 120
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'four',
    colour: 'yellow',
    speed: 90
  },
];

let newLots = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'one',
    colour: 'orange',
    speed: 100,
    owner: 'Ted'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'two',
    colour: 'blue',
    speed: 75
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'three updated',
    colour: 'white',
    speed: 120,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'four',
    colour: 'yellow',
    speed: 90
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: 'five',
    colour: 'green',
    speed: 50
  },
];

let map = existingLots.reduce((acc, obj, idx) => acc.set(obj.id, idx), new Map());
for (let obj of newLots)
  if (map.has(obj.id)) {
    let idx = map.get(obj.id);
    existingLots[idx] = {...existingLots[idx], ...obj};
  } else
    existingLots.push(obj);


console.log(existingLots);
```

The updater part could actually work in your code too, just as `filter()` always gets you an array, `if(updatedObj)` should be `if(updatedObj.length)` and the usage of `updatedObj` would be `updatedObj[0]`. And the `acc =` (or a simple `return`) was missing too.
But all of these array methods (`filter()`, `reduce()`, `map()`) are generally working on a single array, they are not really suitable for appending elements from another array depending on conditions, so the second `if` just could not work - for that purpose you are better off with a simple loop as both answers suggest, and then the updating could happen in that same loop anyway.